# Serializing two different types of extended user models with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am currently building an app that extends the Django `User` model with an `Owner` and a `Customer` version of the User model.  So far they don't have any extra fields, but I plan to add those later on depending on where my app goes.

models.py

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='owner')

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='customer')
```

My dilemma is that I am struggling to figure out to construct the serializer and the views so I can create both a `User` instance as well as a respective `Customer` instance or an `Owner` instance depending on what I want to do.

EDIT for clarity: 
I want to be able to use these to register users as well as update them with the serializer but there will be two different kinds of Users.  Later on they are going to have more fields that are unique to each other but as of now they are just separate models.

Comment: Question is not very clear, Can you explain it more ? What input you are expecting, what output in db you want ? And are you looking for single view and single serializer for both model ?

Comment: you either create 2 ModelSerializers one for each model, or you create a Custom Serializer that asks for both data and assign it yourself

Comment: I have that so far, but I need to be able to create a generic `User` instance as well and match that to the `Customer` or `Owner` instance.

Comment: I am starting a project with same structure. I think for registration/update you have to call to endpoints specific to Customer or Owner. And then for login, you call the authentication endpoint, i.e. using the normal User only